# Can 99-raid-check weekly cronjob be scheduled to run in increments?

Tags: raid5

I have a raid5 on UNIX.  Can I somehow automatically schedule the weekly 99-raid-check to run in increments?  During the day it affects the performance, so I don't want it to be doing its check during the day. The system is running on various inputs that require it to be sync'ed properly, and the check will cause the sync to go off by a number of minutes due to slowed-down performance.